# How to remove rows or filter a recordset or collection

Tags: php, lithium

I would like to know if there is a way to remove rows or filter a recordset or collection.

For example, if I have two tables: one for questions and one for the answer choices. The questions belong to different forms. Questions 1-10 belongs to form a, 11-20 belong to form b. Depending on the answers of the previous questions, certain questions may or may not show up, and certain answers later on may or may not show up. Instead of constantly hitting the database, I want to cache the recordset or collection of questions belonging to each form into memory and filter off of the in memory set of questions per session.

This way each user will only hit the database once, at the beginning of their session, instead of every time they click on next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Collection` object used by the models is extended from `lithium\util\Collection` which provides a method for filtering an existing collection and returning a new one based on a user provided closure.

```
$newQuestions = $oldQuestions->find(function($question) {
    if (your new criteria) { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Simply determine the criteria you wish to apply and perform the filtering in the closure. Once it runs you should have a new `Collection` object with only the records that matched.

Answer (score 2):

After you get a Recordset or Collection from your database, you can execute a couple of filters on it. See the [`lithium\util\Collection`](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/util/Collection.php#L277) for more info.

An example would be

```
$questions = Questions::all();
$form_questions = $questions->find(function($question) {
  if($query->form == 'b') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}), true);
```

To handle keeping these questions persist between page requests, look into [`lithium\storage\Session`](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/storage/Session.php).

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is valid, but joeb's answer is easier to understand, from a newbie's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that simple 'once-per-page' database calls will put much of a strain on your server unless you have truely terrific traffic, but if you do want to do this, the easiest way to do this will be to cache this information in the PHP `$_SESSION` superglobal when a user logs in. Assuming you've set PHP to use filesystem storage (though even if you use database session storage it will have only a tiny affect on performance), you'll have your questions stored in super fast-to-access files which are already pre-built to be unique to each specific user. As soon as a script is loaded, the session file is automatically read into memory and you can access any of the information from there.

### EXAMPLE:

Assuming that your questions table has columns `question_number` and `question_text` and your answers table has the columns `question_number` and `answer_text`:

```
<?php
//on login:
//first get the answer array, so we can use it in the logic below:
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE [criteria]',[connection identifier]) or die(mysql_error());
if (!mysql_num_rows($query)){
   die("No questions!");
}
$answer_array = array();
//create a keyed array that you can access by question number
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $answer_array[$row['question_number']] = $row['answer_text'];
}


//now get the questions and put everything into the session variable 
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE [criteria]',[connection identifier]) or die(mysql_error());
if (!mysql_num_rows($query)){
   die("No questions!");
}
//loop through the results and generate session arrays we can work with later
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   //assign the question to the correct form:
   if ($row['question_number']<=10){
      $session_key = 'form_a';
   } elseif($row['question_number']<=20){
      $session_key = 'form_b';
   } elseif($row['question_number']<=30){
      $session_key = 'form_c';
   } else {
      $session_key = 'form_d';
   }

   //if the session variable does exist yet, create it:
   if (!isset($_SESSION[$session_key])){
      $_SESSION[$session_key] = array();
   }
   //get the existing answer if it exists, otherwise leave the answer blank:
   $my_answer = "";
   if(isset($answer_array[$row['question_number']])){
      $my_answer = $answer_array[$row['question_number']];
   }
   //add this question array as a child array element in the session array, keyed by the question number
   $_SESSION[$session_key][$row['question_number']] = array(
      'question' => $row,
      'answer'   => $my_answer
   );
}
```

Now, if we're loading Form B, for instance, we can just read it out of the session array `$_SESSION['form_b']` and perform any logical switches we want based on the answers to previous questions:

```
$html = "";
foreach($_SESSION['form_b'] as $question_number => $data){
  //perform any logic, for instance, if question 2 from form a is equal to '5', don't show question 3 on form B:
  switch($question_number){
      case '3': if ($_SESSION['form_a']['2']['answer']=='5'){ continue 2; }; break;
  }
  //add the question to the form, and populate the answer if they already answered it earlier:
  $html .= "<label>".$data['question']."<input type='text' value=\"".$data['answer']."\" name='question_".$question_number."' /></label>";
}
```

Then, when you submit each form, in addition to updating the mysql `answers` table, you'll also want to update your _SESSION array. For instance, if you're submitting form B via POST:

```
$form = 'form_b';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if (substr($key,0,strlen('question_')!='question_'){
        continue;                       
    }
    $number = str_replace('question_','',$key); //this will give us the question number
    $saved = add_answer($number,$value); //call the function to insert the new answer into the database (this is a dummy function, and please make sure to escape your variables
    if ($saved){//assuming it saved:
        $_SESSION[$form ][$number]['answer']=$value; //now we've updated the session array as well.
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great advice, but I'm afraid it doesn't answer my question. I need to know how to filter a recordset or collection without having to iterate through every record or document.

Comment: @ton.yeung this is simply a mater of structuring the session variables in a manner you find easy to work with. I'll update the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer, but its still manual iteration. I'm looking for something like a dataview in .net. I also want to work on the recordset or collection itself, so I can pass it to the view as a recordset or collection instead of an array. One last thing, this is a lithium framework specific question. Your answer would work, but it doesn't follow lithium conventions. See the other answers for what I mean.